# Highstocks 2.04 Bug?: Tooltip dates > 20 years displaying as 1st of month

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a line graph with a data source that contains a series of dates and data points.  I've noticed that if any dates in the source are older than 20 years, the tooltip value (this.x) displays as the first of the month, e.g. May 1, 2003, for all dates in the sequence regardless of how old they are.  If the data has dates up to but not exceeding 20 years in the past, the tooltip dates resolve correctly, e.g. Apr 30, 2003 for all dates in the chart.

Below is a fiddle with two charts.  The top has dates greater than 20 years, the bottom less than than 20 years (by a few days).

Here is the function (data is too long to include here - please see the fiddle)

```
$(function () {

    // Create chart1
    $('#container1').highcharts('StockChart', {
        series : [{
            data : data1
        }],
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var out = '<h4>';
                out += Highcharts.dateFormat('%a, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</h4>';
                return out;
            }
        }    
    });

    // Create chart1
    $('#container2').highcharts('StockChart', {
        series : [{
            data : data2
        }],
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var out = '<h4>';
                out += Highcharts.dateFormat('%a, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</h4>';
                return out;
            }
        }    
    });

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dylanmac/k2dvsrj5/2/

See what I mean? Is this a bug or have I misconfigured my chart?

Comment: I think this is a `dataGrouping` issue. If it is grouped, it will show as "<Month> 1", and if not grouped it will show the actual date. Grouping is on by default and happens if there are "too many points" to be efficient.

Comment: Yep that's looks to be the culprit. Unfortunately disabling dataGrouping may have other repercussions that I have to investigate. Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related with the [datagrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping) which approximate dates. You can configure it by units and other opions.